# Reverse engineer RSA algorithm used by HUAWEI Router in Java/Kotlin

Tags: javascript, cryptography, rsa, huawei-mobile-services

I'm trying control my huawei router using its web api, but some things are RSA encrypted. I have the public key, but I am struggling to find the algorithm they use to encrypt things.

The code they use is below:

```js
function doRSAEncrypt(encstring) {
    if (encstring == '') {
        return '';
    }

    if (typeof (g_moduleswitch.encrypt_enabled) == 'undefined' || g_moduleswitch.encrypt_enabled != 1) {
        return encstring;
    }

    if (g_encPublickey.e == '') {
        if (true == g_scarm_login) {
            var pubkeyArray = getPubkey();
            g_encPublickey.e = pubkeyArray[1];
            g_encPublickey.n = pubkeyArray[0];
        } else {
            getEncpubkey();
        }
    }
    var rsa = new RSAKey();
    rsa.setPublic(g_encPublickey.n, g_encPublickey.e);
    encstring = base64_encode(encstring);
    var num = encstring.length / 245;
    var restotal = '';
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        var encdata = encstring.substr(i * 245, 245);
        var res = rsa.encrypt(encdata);
        restotal += res;
    }
    if (restotal.length % 256 != 0) {
        restotal = doRSAEncrypt(encstring);
    }
    return restotal;
}




function parseBigInt(str, r) {
    return new BigInteger(str, r);
}

// PKCS#1 (type 2, random) pad input string s to n bytes, and return a bigint
function pkcs1pad2(s, n) {
    if (n < s.length + 11) { // TODO: fix for utf-8                                                           alert("Message too long for RSA");
        return null;
    }
    var ba = new Array();
    var i = s.length - 1;
    while (i >= 0 && n > 0) {
        var c = s.charCodeAt(i--);
        if (c < 128) { // encode using utf-8            
            ba[--n] = c;
        } else if ((c > 127) && (c < 2048)) {
            ba[--n] = (c & 63) | 128;
            ba[--n] = (c >> 6) | 192;
        } else {
            ba[--n] = (c & 63) | 128;
            ba[--n] = ((c >> 6) & 63) | 128;
            ba[--n] = (c >> 12) | 224;
        }
    }
    ba[--n] = 0;
    var rng = new SecureRandom();
    var x = new Array();
    while (n > 2) { // random non-zero pad        
        x[0] = 0;
        while (x[0] == 0)
            rng.nextBytes(x);
        ba[--n] = x[0];
    }
    ba[--n] = 2;
    ba[--n] = 0;
    return new BigInteger(ba);
}

// "empty" RSA key constructor
function RSAKey() {
    this.n = null;
    this.e = 0;
    this.d = null;
    this.p = null;
    this.q = null;
    this.dmp1 = null;
    this.dmq1 = null;
    this.coeff = null;
}

// Set the public key fields N and e from hex strings
function RSASetPublic(N, E) {
    if (N != null && E != null && N.length > 0 && E.length > 0) {
        this.n = parseBigInt(N, 16);
        this.e = parseInt(E, 16);
    } else alert("Invalid RSA public key");
}

// Perform raw public operation on "x": return x^e (mod n)
function RSADoPublic(x) {
    return x.modPowInt(this.e, this.n);
}

// Return the PKCS#1 RSA PKCS#1 RSA encryption of "text" as an even-length hex string
function RSAEncrypt(text) {
    var m = pkcs1pad2(text, (this.n.bitLength() + 7) >> 3);
    if (m == null)
        return null;
    var c = this.doPublic(m);
    if (c == null)
        return null;
    var h = c.toString(16);
    if ((h.length & 1) == 0)
        return h;
    else        
        return "0" + h;
}

// Return the PKCS#1 RSA encryption of "text" as a Base64-encoded string
function RSAEncryptB64(text) {
    var h = this.encrypt(text);
    if (h)
        return hex2b64(h);
    else        
        return null;
}

// protectedRSAKey.prototype.doPublic = RSADoPublic;

// publicRSAKey.prototype.setPublic = RSASetPublic;
RSAKey.prototype.encrypt = RSAEncrypt;
RSAKey.prototype.encrypt_b64 = RSAEncryptB64;
```

```js
function base64_encode(input) {
    _keyStr = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";
    var output = "";
    var chr1, chr2, chr3, enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
    var i = 0;
    input = _utf8_encode(input);
    while (i < input.length) {
        chr1 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
        chr2 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
        chr3 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
        enc1 = chr1 >> 2;
        enc2 = ((chr1 & 3) << 4) | (chr2 >> 4);
        enc3 = ((chr2 & 15) << 2) | (chr3 >> 6);
        enc4 = chr3 & 63;
        if (isNaN(chr2)) {
            enc3 = enc4 = 64;
        } else if (isNaN(chr3)) {
            enc4 = 64;
        }
        output = output + this._keyStr.charAt(enc1) + this._keyStr.charAt(enc2) + this._keyStr.charAt(enc3) + this._keyStr.charAt(enc4);
    }
    return output;
}



function _utf8_encode(string) {
    string = string.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n");
    var utftext = "";
    for (var n = 0; n < string.length; n++) {
        var c = string.charCodeAt(n);
        if (c < 128) {
            utftext += String.fromCharCode(c);
        } else if ((c > 127) && (c < 2048)) {
            utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 6) | 192);
            utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
        } else {
            utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 12) | 224);
            utftext += String.fromCharCode(((c >> 6) & 63) | 128);
            utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
        }
    }
    return utftext;
}
```

For modulus `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`
and exponent `010001` (both in hex) the string `test123test` yields `59a5a4fe4056612c9892ea2d5108c1e348b2fb70a85a1f0c7b112bfddf058f969e8fc5e797875f63b75eb59160c1df77c7d23dbe481905226d2001f32b4eee59ec795bd113c3606096f8cbdab8ada6d6df00f1621635b7dec60ba1814208a39a3aba2ea527bda2ea522f6b65273525e7fe03478a154904debb11b7523c50432cda45a3638a6b65f768acbcc3ef1ea5c11235e39343042ea570bf220bbad05973e5c6d58af3e64c0ad183b946252c801567fa11029bdc667d2144413a5f943813ef8daf2318079204ec615e68a871e29556cd43495e3ea0a84adbe6b2dbd7e4a8d3be78bdf64a61db1a8c1dd9683499ce9241dbd6ea5bee0325944d01a17d5199` using their encryption.

I tried various RSA modes from Bouncycastle in Java like

- `RSA/ECB/OAEPWITHMD5ANDMGF1PADDING`
- `RSA/ECB/OAEPWITHSHA1ANDMGF1PADDING`
- `RSA/ECB/OAEPWITHSHA-256ANDMGF1PADDING`
- `RSA/ECB/OAEPWITHSHA-384ANDMGF1PADDING`
- `RSA/ECB/OAEPWITHSHA-512ANDMGF1PADDING`
- `RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-1AndMGF1Padding`
- `RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding`

but none of them yielded the same result as the Huawei encrypt function did

Comment: I am trying to reverse their RSA method in Java. I have updated my post to clarify that, but the title already says I want to do it in Java/Kotlin.

Comment: I want to know what type of RSA encryption they are using.

Comment: Since random padding is being used you will always see a different result, even for the same plaintext. That is the expected result.

Comment: Is that a standard way if doing things, and if so, can I replicate it using an existing implementation?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```kotlin
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
import java.math.BigInteger
import java.security.SecureRandom
import java.util.*
import kotlin.math.ceil
import kotlin.math.min

class RSAEncrypt(modulo: String, exponent: String) {
    private val modulo = BigInteger(modulo, 16)
    private val exponent = BigInteger(exponent, 16)

    fun doRSAEncrypt(encstring: String): String {
        val base64String = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encstring.toByteArray())
        val num = base64String.length / 245.0
        var restotal = ""
        for (i in 0 until ceil(num).toInt()) {
            val encryptedData = base64String.substring(i * 245, min(245, base64String.length))
            val res = this.encrypt(encryptedData);
            restotal += res;
        }

        if (restotal.length % 256 !== 0) {
            restotal = doRSAEncrypt(base64String)
        }

        return restotal
    }

    private fun pkcs1pad2(s: String, n: Int): BigInteger? {
        if (n < s.length + 11) { // TODO: fix for utf-8
            return null
        }

        var n = n
        val ba = MutableList(n) { 0 }
        var i = s.length - 1;
        while (i >= 0 && n > 0) {
            val c = Character.codePointAt(s, i--)
            if (c < 128) { // encode using utf-8
                ba[--n] = c;
            } else if ((c > 127) && (c < 2048)) {
                ba[--n] = (c and 63) or 128;
                ba[--n] = (c shr 6) or 192;
            } else {
                ba[--n] = (c and 63) or 128;
                ba[--n] = ((c shr 6) and 63) or 128;
                ba[--n] = (c shr 12) or 224;
            }
        }
        ba[--n] = 0;
        val rng = SecureRandom()
        val x = ByteArray(n) { 0 }
        while (n > 2) {
            x[0] = 0;
            while (x[0].toInt() == 0) {
                rng.nextBytes(x)
            }
            ba[--n] = x[0].toInt()
        }
        ba[--n] = 2;
        ba[--n] = 0;

        val baos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        for (item in ba) {
            if (item < -128 || item > 127) {
                throw Exception("You code is shit")
            }

            baos.write(item)
        }

        return BigInteger(baos.toByteArray())
    }

    private fun doPublic(x: BigInteger): BigInteger {
        return x.modPow(this.exponent, this.modulo)
    }

    private fun encrypt(text: String): String? {
        val maxLength = (this.modulo.bitLength() + 7) shr 3
        val m = pkcs1pad2(text, maxLength) ?: return null

        val c = this.doPublic(m)

        var h = c.toString(16);
        val length = h.length;

        // fix zero before result
        for (i in 0 until maxLength * 2 - length) {
            h = "0$h";
        }

        return h
    }
}
```

Implemented in Kotlin